# How am I supposed to use another thread to get cursor position and update 2 labels with the coordinates?

Tags: java, javafx

So I have this in the initiallize:

```
    double x = 1, y = 1;
    while (x != 0 || y != 0) {
        x = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getX();
        y = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getY();
        cursorXPositionLabel.setText("" + x);
        cursorYPositionLabel.setText("" + y);
        System.out.println("X = " + x + "\tY = " + y);
    }
```

But the application does not start until the cursor is not at (0,0) coordinate. When it is, the application starts and the labels show 0, 0. I want the application to start, and while moving the cursor, update the labels with the actual coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I did not understand you wanted it to extend beyond the application check out this example it is tested and working

```
public class Main extends Application {

    private Label xLabel;
    private Label yLabel;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        xLabel = new Label("X Coordinate: 0");
        yLabel = new Label("y Coordinate: 0");

        VBox vBox = new VBox();
        vBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        vBox.getChildren().addAll(xLabel, yLabel);

        Scene scene = new Scene(vBox);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setWidth(300);
        primaryStage.setHeight(300);
        primaryStage.show();

        updateCoordintates();
    }

    private void updateCoordintates(){
        new Thread(()->{ //Splits off the Main thread
            double lastX = 1;
            double lastY = 1;
            while (true) { //Will run forever you may want to change this not sure of your constraints
                double x = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getX();
                double y = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getY();

                //The platform.runlater will allow you to post the change to the screen when available
                if(x!=lastX)
                    Platform.runLater(()->xLabel.setText(String.valueOf(x)));
                if(y!=lastY)
                    Platform.runLater(()->yLabel.setText(String.valueOf(y)));

                lastX = x;
                lastY = y;
                System.out.println("X = " + x + "\tY = " + y);
            }
        }).start();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) { launch(args); }
}
```

Y̶o̶u̶ ̶d̶o̶ ̶n̶o̶t̶ ̶n̶e̶e̶d̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶i̶t̶ ̶o̶n̶ ̶a̶ ̶b̶a̶c̶k̶g̶r̶o̶u̶n̶d̶ ̶t̶h̶r̶e̶a̶d̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶t̶h̶i̶s̶ ̶j̶u̶s̶t̶ ̶f̶i̶r̶e̶ ̶a̶ ̶`.̶s̶e̶t̶O̶n̶M̶o̶u̶s̶e̶M̶o̶v̶e̶d̶` ̶f̶r̶o̶m̶ ̶w̶h̶a̶t̶e̶v̶e̶r̶ ̶c̶o̶n̶t̶a̶i̶n̶e̶r̶ ̶y̶o̶u̶ ̶a̶r̶e̶ ̶u̶s̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶h̶e̶r̶e̶ ̶i̶s̶ ̶a̶ ̶r̶u̶n̶n̶a̶b̶l̶e̶ ̶e̶x̶a̶m̶p̶l̶e̶ ̶t̶h̶a̶t̶ ̶u̶p̶d̶a̶t̶e̶s̶ ̶t̶h̶e̶ ̶c̶o̶o̶r̶d̶i̶n̶a̶t̶e̶s̶ ̶o̶n̶ ̶m̶o̶v̶e̶m̶e̶n̶t̶

Comment: I would like it to work in another application aswell. If I open the firefox and moving my cursor there, should show the coordinate.

Comment: So my container should be the screen of my monitor actually.

Comment: If this solution solves the problem you were having please accept the answer by clicking the check next to it so that others do now think the topic is open

Comment: I do not know where is that "check", but the program doing exactly what I need.